# zalando operator/AWS IAM cluster clone

Tags: postgresql, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I'm trying without success to clone new PostgreSQL cluster managed by Zalando operator v1.10.0.
I use AWS + S3 + IAM Roles. Backups work fine and I can see in it from a pod:

```
root@test-postgresql-0:/home/postgres# envdir "/run/etc/wal-e.d/env" wal-g backup-list
name                          modified             wal_segment_backup_start
base_000000010000000000000002 2023-08-17T12:47:14Z 000000010000000000000002
root@test-postgresql-0:/home/postgres#
```

I tried to clone using this manifest:

```
spec:
  clone:
    uid: "d4355d73-f5d6-4786-a093-7239125a2a12"
    cluster: "test-postgresql"
    timestamp: "2023-08-17T12:47:00+00:00"
    s3_wal_path: "s3://el-postgres-backup-int/spilo/postgresql-test-postgresql/wal/14/"
```

When I check if the new pod has access and can "see" the backup:

```
root@test-clone-postgresql-0:/home/postgres# envdir "/run/etc/wal-e.d/env-clone-test-postgresql/" wal-g backup-list
name                          modified             wal_segment_backup_start
base_000000010000000000000002 2023-08-17T12:47:14Z 000000010000000000000002
root@test-clone-postgresql-0:/home/postgres#
```

The answer is "YES", it can.

But startup logs showed wired result:

```
2023-08-17 12:59:10,460 INFO: No PostgreSQL configuration items changed, nothing to reload.
2023-08-17 12:59:10,461 INFO: Lock owner: None; I am test-clone-postgresql-0
2023-08-17 12:59:10,541 INFO: trying to bootstrap a new cluster
2023-08-17 12:59:10,541 INFO: Running custom bootstrap script: envdir "/run/etc/wal-e.d/env-clone-test-postgresql" python3 /scripts/clone_with_wale.py --recovery-target-time="2023-08-17T12:47:00+00:00"
2023-08-17 12:59:10,597 INFO: Trying s3://el-postgres-backup-int/spilo/postgresql-test-postgresql/wal/14/ for clone
ERROR: 2023/08/17 12:59:13.824667 failed to list s3 folder: 'spilo/postgresql-test-postgresql/wal/14/basebackups_005/': AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 5TPDP0S5NSN16QFA, host id: 4u4XDWohJwKE+q5R7qMUACDr2tdg//CBGCiyaHW56I8tRj1jeIDrDWpf1RRJeBKN9Y02xmQgXxez7NiihScwOw==
2023-08-17 12:59:13,827 ERROR: Clone failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scripts/clone_with_wale.py", line 185, in main
    run_clone_from_s3(options)
  File "/scripts/clone_with_wale.py", line 166, in run_clone_from_s3
    backup_name, update_envdir = find_backup(options.recovery_target_time, env)
  File "/scripts/clone_with_wale.py", line 150, in find_backup
    backup_list = list_backups(env)
  File "/scripts/clone_with_wale.py", line 84, in list_backups
    output = subprocess.check_output(backup_list_cmd, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['wal-g', 'backup-list']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2023-08-17 12:59:13,834 INFO: removing initialize key after failed attempt to bootstrap the cluster
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/patroni", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/__main__.py", line 144, in main
    return patroni_main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/__main__.py", line 136, in patroni_main
    abstract_main(Patroni, schema)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/daemon.py", line 108, in abstract_main
    controller.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/__main__.py", line 106, in run
    super(Patroni, self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/daemon.py", line 65, in run
    self._run_cycle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/__main__.py", line 109, in _run_cycle
    logger.info(self.ha.run_cycle())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1771, in run_cycle
    info = self._run_cycle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1593, in _run_cycle
    return self.post_bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1484, in post_bootstrap
    self.cancel_initialization()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/patroni/ha.py", line 1477, in cancel_initialization
    raise PatroniFatalException('Failed to bootstrap cluster')
patroni.exceptions.PatroniFatalException: 'Failed to bootstrap cluster'
/etc/runit/runsvdir/default/patroni: finished with code=1 signal=0
/etc/runit/runsvdir/default/patroni: exceeded maximum number of restarts 5
stopping /etc/runit/runsvdir/default/patroni
```

Does anybody have any ideas why can it be? Cause I don't have already.

Comment: I suggest opening an issue in the GitHub repository for Zalando's operator.

Comment: Created:
[Issue](https://github.com/zalando/postgres-operator/issues/2394)